# Use of undeclared identifier 'locationManager'

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

Everything is fine till I add this line:
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
Then I get the error.

I also get errors for these lines: (Xcode suggests I use "_LongitudeLabel"?

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {
    longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? Does the tutorial have errors or have I done something wrong?
Thanks!

This is ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation MyLocationViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@end

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}

@end
```

This is ViewController.h file:

```
//  ViewController.h
//  MyLocationDemo
//
//  Created by Ian Nicoll on 12/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ian Nicoll. All rights reserved.
//
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LatitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LongitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;
@end

@interface MyLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is an error on your part. You declared `locationManager` in `MyLocationViewController` but try to initialize it in the `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController`, where it of course does not exist.

The second issue is an issue with the instructions. When you declare an `@property`, the default behavior is to create an instance variable with an underscore in front of it.

So `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LatitudeLabel;` can be accessed as `self.latitudeLabel` (which goes through the setter/getter) or just `_latitudeLabel` which accesses the ivar directly. The latter is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still stuck with the first issue, what do I do to fix it, I try moving the declaration everywhere LOL, but not sure where I'm suppose to move it to, nothing works!

Comment: Either move the variable declaration into `ViewController` or move all the code that uses the variable into `MyLocationViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the build now is Succeeded (though I'm not 100& sure I got things right) but now I get a warning for this line: locationManager.delegate = self; - **Assigning to 'id'from incompatible type 'ViewControler *const_strong'**
Would you know how to fix this warning?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _LatitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}

@end
```